# How to extract Geolocation metadata from an Apple Live Photo?

Tags: ffmpeg, geolocation, exif, exiftool, iphoto

I'm trying to organize my photo collection and convert .mov files to .jpeg files while retaining all of the meta data that has been stored.  I'm running into a problem with Apple's "Live Photos" though...

I recently downloaded all of the photos from my iCloud account and found that many have been stored as .mov files as "Live Photos".  As I only want to include photos in this collection, I'd like to convert all of these .mov files to .jpg files.

So... I'm trying to use python and shell commands to do this.  Here's an extract of my code:

```
# Convert the .mov file into a series of jpegs using ffmpeg
os.system(f'ffmpeg -i {movie} -r {numFrames} -map_metadata 0 -movflags use_metadata_tags {imageRoot}_%0004d.jpg')

# ... some code to find the best slice of the movie to keep as an image ...

# Add any meta tags that may have been missed
os.system(f'exiftool -tagsFromFile {movie} {image}"
```

Unfortunately, the Geolocation metadata isn't being copied from the .mov file to the .jpg files.  exiftool {movie}.mov doesn't list any GPS or Geolocation tags either, but I know that this data is included somewhere within the file as Apple is able to map the location that the 2 second video was taken.  Any thoughts as to how I can extract this meta data from Apple's Live Photo .mov clips?

Thanks in advance.

PP

Comment: You might try adding the `-ee` option using a command such as `exiftool -ee -gps* FILE`  If exiftool still doesn't show anything, you might head over to the [exiftool forums](https://exiftool.org/forum).  If you can provide a sample you know has gps data, Phil Harvey, the author of exiftool, might be able to add support.

Comment: Thanks.  Yep... I tried -ee, but it didn't have anything either.  I have a feeling the GPS location of Live Photos are stored in a compressed, proprietary field, but have not been able to find confirmation of that anywhere.  Will try Phil...

Comment: Think I found it.  The latitude and longitude are there, but then I have to convert that to a City, State,and Country using geopy.  Seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

think I found it. The latitude and longitude are there, but then I have to convert that to a City, State,and Country using geopy. Seems to work now